Serving a pygame game using pygbag using python sockets
I have created a game in pygame and am using pygbag to try to get it to work on the web. It created a local server on localhost:8000 and it worked. Now I am trying to create a simple socket server that serves the HTML code that pygbag created, so that people on the local network can connect and play. However, once I start: I just get a glitched green bar.
Here is the server code:
import socket

html = open("build/web/index.txt", "r", errors = "ignore").read() # open html code saved as a text file in another directory, to store as a variable
HOST = "172.17.4.193"
PORT = 65432
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(5)
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print(addr)
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    conn.send(bytes('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n', encoding="utf-8"))
    conn.send(bytes('Content-Type: text/html\n', encoding="utf-8"))
    conn.send(bytes('\n', encoding="utf-8"))
    conn.send(bytes(html, encoding="utf-8"))
    conn.close()

Tried changing localhost to 127.0.0.1, as well as using ipv6 instead of ipv4. Still produced the same glitch.

at which statement do you get this glitch?
Can you run these statements in the python interpretor and check that?

How was index.txt saved and what encoding?  Why are you ignoring errors on reading it?  Recommend saving and loading explicitly with encoding='utf8' and don't ignore errors.

Also use Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

@AlbinPaul I am not sure at which statement this glitch occurs. I entered dev mode by adding "?-i" at the and of the link, in order to see where the problem was. However, it simply just exited the interpreter and didn't show any error message. It's stuck on the green bar. Here's a picture: https://imgur.com/a/5riYLUr

@MarkTolonen Pygbag generated the HTML file. I simply copied this HTML and pasted it into a txt file, as the open() function doesn't work on HTML files.  I'm not sure what you mean by encoding - it's just a text file. There was no particular reason why I used utf-8; it's what I regularly use. How exactly do I save explicitly with encoding = "utf8"?

You definitely should read The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!).  Why do you think the open() function doesn't work on HTML files?  Every text file has an encoding...it's the map between bytes and characters.  If you open the file with the wrong encoding, you don't get the correct characters.

It may not be your current problem if, say, you are on Linux and the default for open() is UTF-8-encoding and you happened to save the text file in UTF-8 encoding, but if you don't know, it definitely could be the problem.  Windows, for example, does not default to UTF-8 encoding with open().  Especially true if you are ignoring errors on open().

@MarkTolonen So are you saying that the problem with this is the encoding of the file? In that case which encoding should I use, and how do I check the encoding of the text file?

Also, I used errors = "ignore", because if I don't, Python raises the error:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp932' codec can't decode byte 0x8e in position 9474: illegal multibyte sequence

It's likely the problem, since it appears you are reading a file that isn't encoded in code page 932 and ignoring the errors, which appears to be the default on your (probably) Japanese-localized Windows system.  Use an editor that can save text in UTF-8 encoding (e.g. Notepad++) and use open('index.html', encoding='utf8') (and it will read an HTML file).  Really, read the link above about Unicode.

I opened the HTML file in Notepad++, and notepad++ was showing that the file was already in utf-8, in the bottom-right corner.
